# My checkout got a width of 1500%, how do UI library grid make sense here?

Tags: less, debugging, magento2.3.2

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.2 and using the latest Magento, the `<div class=".opc_wrapper">` in our checkout got a width of 1500% making it ugly.

We are actually using https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass as a theme, so the issue might come from there. Anyways, I digged that down and compared with the less theme and it boils down to this:

In [checkout.less L134](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/cac46e0c6997d179803376827a5aa8ab3c2f0163/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout/_checkout.less#L134)

```
.opc-wrapper {
    &:extend(.abs-add-box-sizing-desktop-m all);
    .lib-layout-column(2, 1, @checkout-wrapper__columns);
    padding-right: @indent__l;
}
```

**@checkout-wrapper__columns equals to 8 a bit earlier in the file**

If I remove the `.lib-layout-column`, the `width: 1500%` is not set, so it is coming from there.

Going down the rabbit hole, after some [strange looping construct](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/cac46e0c6997d179803376827a5aa8ab3c2f0163/lib/web/css/source/lib/_layout.less#L107) in  brings us finally to the `[grids LESS file][3]`, which (in the SASS version) calculates a width of 1500%.

Sure this is not a core bug, because we use a custom theme.

But in order do debug the issue, I need to understand, what the core blank theme is trying to accomplish there.

My understanding of

```
.lib-layout-column(@_total-columns, @_order, @_width) {
```

is, that I specific the width in number of columns?

So if I call that with total-columns = 2
order = 1 (what is that for?)
and the width parameter of 8, it kind of makes sense that this becomes super wide.

And this is already in the core's blank theme.

So what is going on there? How is lib-layout-column to be used?

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic as I now have the exact same issue!

I can answer one part of your question (all be it months later):

```
.lib-layout-column(@_total-columns, @_order, @_width) {
```

This breaks down as follows:

- Total columns is 2 (this and the sidebar)
- Order is 1 (because you want this before the righthand sidebar)
- Width is 8 (and the sidebar is 4 which totals 12 as per the grid model that Magento uses)

Did you manage to resolve this in the end? I'm stuck too and the only thing I can think of is setting a max-width which will solve it. I'd rather find the cause though.

Comment: I did not really solve it -- I think I used a hack. Keep on digging :) Which version are you on?

Comment: Ahhh, that's a shame. I'll spend a little more time on it and if I can't get to the bottom of it I'll just set a max-width. Currently on 2.3.3 - thank you anyway :)